# all (of) Mary's paintings?

Tags: possessive-s-vs-of

I'm wondering whether the preposition "of" is necessary in the following sentence:

1. All (of) Mary's paintings are now on display.

Compare #1 with #2, which seems acceptable without "of":

2. All (of) her paintings are now on display.

Do you perceive any distinctions between pronouns and proper names, where the presence of "of" is concerned?

I'd appreciate your judgments on the sentences.

Comment: Relevant: [“All of” + possessives](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188355) maybe the comments there will be of some help.

Answer (score 1):

> ## Preposition
>
> *noun, Grammar.*
>
> 1.
>   any member of a class of words found in many languages that are used before nouns, pronouns, or other substantives to form phrases functioning as modifiers of verbs, nouns, or adjectives, and that typically express a spatial, temporal, or other relationship, as in, on, by, to, since.

As far as I understand, prepositions exist to provide **clarity** and **explicity form relatonships between words**. I'm sure you could communicate your meaning quite effectively without them, but it would be a lot easier for everyone if you didn't. :)

In fact, really, there isn't any wrong way to speak. For instance, I have some mentally handicapped friends who speak in a way that many consider incorrect, but **if it works**, is it wrong? Or is it just different? :)

You might enjoy [this article](http://www.pbs.org/speak/speech/correct/prescriptivism/), if you're curious about what I meant.

Personally I love prepositions and think we should use them as often as we could, though. Have a good day!